# Policy to connect subscription's activity logs to log analytics

Tags: azure, logging, policy, azure-log-analytics

I'm looking for custom policy to connect and get activity/audit logs from Azure to Log Analytics workspace. There are not build in policy to this so it would need to be done with custom policy. Has anybody created or seen this kinda policy because I have not been able to find? Policy should be AuditIfNotExists and should take Log Analytics workspace as a parameter. I'm not policy specialist so finding policy, would help a lot.

Answer (score 0):

There is no policy to set this up but it is possible to set it up. I got this information from this [tutorial](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/itops-talk-blog/how-to-create-azure-monitor-alerts-for-non-compliant-azure/ba-p/713466):

"The Azure policy compliance status is logged in the Azure subscription’s Activity logs. The Azure Log Analytics workspace can be configured to collect Azure Activity logs from any subscriptions in the same tenant. Azure Monitor alert rules can then be created to execute queries in the Log Analytics workspace on a schedule and generate alerts when non-compliant resources are detected by the query. "

1. Connect log Analytics workspace to desired subscription
2. Add Kusto queries in the workspace to get information needed:

Here is an example of a kusto query for Get a list of non-compliant resources from a single policy (using “audit-resources-without-tags-policyDef” definition as an example):
let policyDefId = 'audit-resources-without-tags-policyDef'; AzureActivity | where Category == 'Policy' and Level != 'Informational' | extend p=todynamic(Properties) | extend policies=todynamic(tostring(p.policies)) | mvexpand policy = policies | where policy.policyDefinitionName in (policyDefId) | distinct ResourceId

3. You can set up alerts using Azure Monitor with a custom log search